# How can I add a XML as an inner text within another XML, as a parameter of a SOAP request

Tags: xml, soap, encode, urlencode

An example, I want to send a XML as param in a XML SOAP:

```
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <doc:makeSomething>
         <param1>blah blah</param1>
         <pamar2>3.14159</param2>
         <xml>
                 <!-- this is what i want to insert -->
                 <myDOC>
                     <tag1>xxx</tag1>
                     <tag2>yyy</tag2>
                     .....
                     .....
                 </myDOC>                 
         </xml>
      </doc:makeSomething>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What can I do? Use urlencode?

Comment: The solution is:
   
   ```
      <doc:makeSomething>
         <param1>blah blah</param1>
         <pamar2>3.14159</param2>
         <xml>
                 <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                        <myDOC>
                            <tag1>xxx</tag1>
                            <tag2>yyy</tag2>
                            .....
                            .....
                        </myDOC>                 
                ]]>                 
         </xml>
      </doc:makeSomething>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `fn:document(...)` function of XSLT-1.0.
So use an XSLT processor with the following files to insert `insert.xml` at the desired position in the input XML. The following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:doc="http://some.doc">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <doc:makeSomething>
            <param1>blah blah</param1>
            <param2>3.14159</param2>
            <xml>
                <!-- this is what i want to insert -->
                <myDOC>
                    <tag1>xxx</tag1>
                    <tag2>yyy</tag2>
                    .....
                    .....
                </myDOC>
            </xml>
        </doc:makeSomething>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this XML file named `insert.xml` to insert

```
<Items>   
 <Item id='1'/>
 <Item id='3'/>
 <Item id='5'/>
 <Item id='7'/>
</Items>
```

with this XSLT-1.0 stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:doc="http://some.doc" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/doc:makeSomething/xml">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('insert.xml')"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will result in the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:doc="http://some.doc">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <doc:makeSomething>
            <param1>blah blah</param1>
            <param2>3.14159</param2>
            <xml>
                <!-- Here the file 'insert.xml' is inserted -->
                <Items>
                    <Item id="1"/>
                    <Item id="3"/>
                    <Item id="5"/>
                    <Item id="7"/>
                </Items>
                <!-- Here the already present part is copied -->
                <myDOC>
                    <tag1>xxx</tag1>
                    <tag2>yyy</tag2>
                    .....
                    .....
                </myDOC>
            </xml>
        </doc:makeSomething>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is what XSLT does.
It is one of the easiest ways to achieve the desired task.

Comment: That is not than i need, that is if you want to add or insert new nodes from another xml. On the other hand I need to add a xml as a inner Text,

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to envolve the data-xml between  ]]>

```
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <doc:makeSomething>
         <param1>blah blah</param1>
         <pamar2>3.14159</param2>
         <xml>
                 <![CDATA[
                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                 <myDOC>
                     <tag1>xxx</tag1>
                     <tag2>yyy</tag2>
                     .....
                     .....
                 </myDOC>                 
                 ]]>
         </xml>
      </doc:makeSomething>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```